# I can to import waipy

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, package

I want to import thez package waipy, I use import waipy but it show this erros: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.
can you help me pleasse to import it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, Think you for your .

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the comments and indentations within the waipy/cwt/**lib_wavelet.py** file.